# Yii2 errorOptions encode false not working in ActiveForm - HTML in error message

Tags: yii2

In the rules I have a custom message with html text:

```
[ 'user_email', 'required', 'message' => 'Don\'t have one? <a href="/contact-us">Give us a call</a>' ],
```

My form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin( [
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'validationUrl'        => '/user/validate-register',
] ); ?>

<?= $form->field( $model, 'user_email', [
        'errorOptions' => [
            'encode' => false,
        ]
] )->textInput( [ 'maxlength' => true ] ) ?>
```

Ass soon as I put errorOptions in, no error message displays... it's highlighted red, but no inline message appears.

With no `errorOptions` message html is encoded
[image: html not encoded]

With `errorOptions` no error message appears at all

[image: no error message at all]

Answer (score 7):

Add class `help-block` to apply css correctly.

**Form**

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
   'fieldConfig' => [
      'errorOptions' => [
           'encode' => false,
           'class' => 'help-block'
       ],
   ],
]);
```

**Field**

```
<?= $form->field( $model, 'user_email', [
    'errorOptions' => [
        'encode' => false,
        'class' => 'help-block'
    ]
])->textInput( [ 'maxlength' => true ] ) ?>
```